# React component not setting state after mocking redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

Here is my test

```js
const initialRootState = {
  accounts: [mockAccounts],
  isLoading: false
}

describe('Account Dashboard', () => {
  let rootState = {
    ...initialRootState
  }

  const mockStore = configureStore()
  const store = mockStore({ ...rootState })
  const mockFunction = jest.fn()

  jest.spyOn(Redux, 'useDispatch').mockImplementation(() => mockFunction)
  jest
    .spyOn(Redux, 'useSelector')
    .mockImplementation((state) => state(store.getState()))

  afterEach(() => {
    mockFunction.mockClear()

    // Reseting state
    rootState = {
      ...initialRootState
    }
  })

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
        <TestWrapper>
          <AccountDashboard />
        </TestWrapper>
    )
    console.log(wrapper)
  })
})
```

In my component I am mapping accounts from the state. In my test I am getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

I would like to test an `if statement` I am using in my component to ensure it's returning the proper view based on the number of accounts I am receiving.

However, when I `console.log(store.getState())` it is printing correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my test was working incorrectly due to my selector function in my component being implement incorrectly. So the test was actually working properly!

Note: My team is currently using mocked data(waiting for the API team to finish up endpoints).

Originally the `useSelector` function in my component(that I was testing) looked like:

```js
const { accounts, isLoading } = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => state.accounts,
  shallowEqual
)
```

When I updated this to:

```js
const { accounts, isAccountsLoading } = useSelector(
  (state: RootState) => ({
    accounts: state.accounts.accounts,
    isAccountsLoading: state.accounts.isLoading
  }),
  shallowEqual
)
```

My tests worked - here are my final tests:

```js
describe('App', () => {
  let rootState = {
    ...initialState
  }

  const mockStore = configureStore()
  const store = mockStore({ ...rootState })

  jest.spyOn(Redux, 'useDispatch').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn())
  jest
    .spyOn(Redux, 'useSelector')
    .mockImplementation((state) => state(store.getState()))

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()

    // Resetting State
    rootState = {
      ...initialState
    }
  })

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <TestWrapper>
        <Dashboard />
      </TestWrapper>
    )

    expect(wrapper.find('[data-test="app"]').exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.find(verticalCard).exists()).toBe(false)
    expect(wrapper.find(horizontalCard).exists()).toBe(true)
  })


  it('renders multiple properly', () => {
    rootState.info = mockData.info
    const wrapper = mount(
      <TestWrapper>
        <Dashboard />
      </TestWrapper>
    )

    expect(wrapper.find(verticalCard).exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.find(horizontalCard).exists()).toBe(false)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to test a Redux connected component, I'd recommend steering away from mocking its internals and instead to test it as if it were a React component connected to a real Redux store.

For example, here's a factory function for mounting connected components with `enzyme`:

**utils/withRedux.jsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import rootReducer from "../path/to/reducers";

/*
  You can skip recreating this "store" by importing/exporting
  the real "store" from wherever you defined it in your app
*/
export const store = createStore(rootReducer);

/**
 * Factory function to create a mounted Redux connected wrapper for a React component
 *
 * @param {ReactNode} Component - the Component to be mounted via Enzyme
 * @function createElement - Creates a wrapper around the passed in component with incoming props so that we can still use "wrapper.setProps" on the root
 * @returns {ReactWrapper} - a mounted React component with a Redux store.
 */
export const withRedux = Component =>
  mount(
    React.createElement(props => (
      <Provider store={store}>
        {React.cloneElement(Component, props)}
      </Provider>
    )),
    options
  );

export default withRedux;
```

Now, using the above factory function, we can test the connected component by simply using `store.dispatch`:

****tests**/ConnectedComponent.jsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import withRedux, { store } from "../path/to/utils/withRedux";
import ConnectedComponent from "../index";

const fakeAccountData = [{...}, {...}, {...}];

describe("Connected Component", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = withRedux(<ConnectedComponent />);
  });

  it("initially shows a loading indicator", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(".loading-indicator")).exists().toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("displays the accounts when data is present", () => {
    /*
      Ideally, you'll be dispatching an action function for simplicity
      
      For example: store.dispatch(setAccounts(fakeAccountData));

      But for ease of readability, I've written it out below.
    */
    store.dispatch({ type: "ACCOUNTS/LOADED", accounts: fakeAccountData }));

    // update the component to reflect the prop changes
    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.find(".loading-indicator")).exists().toBeFalsy();
    expect(wrapper.find(".accounts").exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This vastly simplifies not having to mock the store/useSelector/useDispatch over and over when you start to test other Redux connected components.

---

On a side note, you can skip this entirely if you use react-redux's `connect` function while exporting the unconnected component. Instead of importing the default export, you can import the unconnected component within your test...

Example component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export const Example = ({ accounts, isLoading }) => { ... };

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ ... });

const mapDispatchToProps = { ... };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Example);
```

Example test:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { Example } from "../index";

const initProps = {
  accounts: [],
  isLoading: true
};

const fakeAccountData = [{...}, {...}, {...}];

describe("Unconnected Example Component", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Example {...initProps } />);
  });

  it("initially shows a loading indicator", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(".loading-indicator")).exists().toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("displays the accounts when data is present", () => {
    wrapper.setProps({ accounts: fakeAccountData, isLoading: false });
    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.find(".loading-indicator")).exists().toBeFalsy();
    expect(wrapper.find(".accounts").exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, however I'm not using redux connect. I figured out it was an issue in my selector in my component. The test was working properly! Setting the state was incorrectly implemented.

Comment: The first option mentioned above (wrapping your component in a Redux `Provider`) will work regardless of whether or not you're using hooks or `connect`. This has the added advantage of testing the Redux flow as a whole unit so that you won't need to mock anything. Also, the other advantage is that it'll be more flexible if you ever decide to change some of the Redux logic (since it's utilizing the actual flow, you won't need to refactor any mocks). Either way, glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Definitely, it's a great idea to wrap in a provider!!